# AWS Lambda : "Parameter validation failed"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a lambda fucntion where I am sending email and the mail template is fetching as an object from an S3 bucket. I have ran the code locally in my computer and I works fine. When I paste it inside my lambda function, it shows following error.

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Message.Body.Html.Data, value: b\"<html>\\n<head></head>\\n<body>\\n  <h1>Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)</h1>\\n  <p>This email was sent with\\n    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses/'>Amazon SES</a> using the\\n    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/'>\\n      AWS SDK for Python (Boto)</a>.</p>\\n</body>\\n</html>\", type: <class 'bytes'>, valid types: <class 'str'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      65,
      "lambda_handler",
      "Source=SENDER,"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      314,
      "_api_call",
      "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      586,
      "_make_api_call",
      "api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      621,
      "_convert_to_request_dict",
      "api_params, operation_model)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py",
      291,
      "serialize_to_request",
      "raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())"
    ]
  ]
}

Request ID:
"7b13a612-97f6-4278-9825-724abeaa3b51"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 7b13a612-97f6-4278-9825-724abeaa3b51 Version: $LATEST
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Message.Body.Html.Data, value: b"<html>\n<head></head>\n<body>\n  <h1>Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)</h1>\n  <p>This email was sent with\n    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses/'>Amazon SES</a> using the\n    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/'>\n      AWS SDK for Python (Boto)</a>.</p>\n</body>\n</html>", type: <class 'bytes'>, valid types: <class 'str'>: ParamValidationError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 65, in lambda_handler
    Source=SENDER,
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 621, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py", line 291, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Message.Body.Html.Data, value: b"<html>\n<head></head>\n<body>\n  <h1>Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)</h1>\n  <p>This email was sent with\n    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses/'>Amazon SES</a> using the\n    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/'>\n      AWS SDK for Python (Boto)</a>.</p>\n</body>\n</html>", type: <class 'bytes'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

END RequestId: 7b13a612-97f6-4278-9825-724abeaa3b51
REPORT RequestId: 7b13a612-97f6-4278-9825-724abeaa3b51  Duration: 1608.47 ms    Billed Duration: 1700 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 71 MB
```

I have checked when I load the template from S3 bucket it shows the following error in lambda. When I declare the BODY_HTML inside my code and not fetch it from S3 in Lambda, it works fine. Here is my code now :

```
import json
import os
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

SENDER = "***********"
RECIPIENT = "************"
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
def lambda_handler(event, context):            
    CHARSET = "UTF-8"
    client = boto3.client('ses',aws_access_key_id=******,
                              aws_secret_access_key=*****,region_name='us-east-1')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=*********,
                                  aws_secret_access_key=***********,region_name='us-east-1')
    s3_response_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='my s3 bucket', Key='template.html')
    object_content = s3_response_object['Body'].read()
    BODY_HTML = object_content
    SUBJECT = "sqs-poc-lambda test email"
    BODY_TEXT = ("This is a test email for sqs-poc-lambda"
                )

    try:
        #Provide the contents of the email.
        response = client.send_email(
            Destination={
                'ToAddresses': [
                    RECIPIENT,
                ],
            },
            Message={
                'Body': {
                    'Html': {
                        'Charset': CHARSET,
                        'Data': BODY_HTML,
                    },
                    'Text': {
                        'Charset': CHARSET,
                        'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                    },
                },
                'Subject': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': SUBJECT,
                },
            },
            Source=SENDER,
        )

    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
        print(response['MessageId'])
```

)

It should return the message ID successfully in the `Function Logs`. Any help on this? I cannot see any logic behind this.

Comment: It's a bad practice to have `access_key`s in code, try to use roles instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to believe that the second code works because it contains the same error that is reported in the first error log. I have copied the code and it fails in the same way.

Issue can be spot by reading this message from error log.

Invalid type for parameter Message.Body.Html.Data, value: b"...  ", **type: class bytes, valid types: class 'str'**: ParamValidationError.

Body should be of type string but `object_content`

```
object_content = s3_response['Body'].read()
```

is of type bytes. You need to convert it to string. E.g. `BODY_HTML = str(object_content)`

**IMPORTANT**

Do **NOT** store permanent credentials in your lambda code.

```
client = boto3.client('ses',aws_access_key_id=******,
                          aws_secret_access_key=*****,region_name='us-east-1')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=*********,
                          aws_secret_access_key=***********,region_name='us-east-1')
```

Give permissions to your lambda function via Lambda Execution Role.

And if you need to provide cross account access to your lambda function then include `sts:AssumeRole` permissions in that role and then use temporary credentials obtained by calling `sts:AssumeRole`

```
client = boto3.client(
    'ses',
    aws_access_key_id=...,
    aws_secret_access_key=...,
    aws_session_token=... // !!!
)
```

But again, **NEVER** store permanent credentials in your function code. Are you sure that next time you place your code in some public repository you will not forget to replace those values with `******`? Each time?

Comment: thank you Matus. I am just getting started with AWS services and I really uploaded them open source by replacing with *****.